# Always have to clean XPages project after every code change

Tags: xpages

I'm building a new XPages front end to an existing IBM Notes application. The XPages UI exists in it's own database - so that only contains the XPages and custom controls along with some script libraries and Java classes. All design elements are signed with the same id.

Following any code change I need to clean the project before the change is reflected in the browser. If I just rebuild the project I get "Error 500. HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception".

The log file error-log-0.xml doesn't contain any additional info :-

```
2017-08-29T14:24:47.775+01:00 SEVERE CLFAD0141E: Error processing XPage request   
2017-08-29T14:24:47.790+01:00 SEVERE CLFAD0211E: Exception thrown   
2017-08-29T14:24:47.822+01:00 SEVERE CLFAD0246E: Exception occurred servicing request for: /dev/test.nsf/home.xsp - HTTP Code: 500
```

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: What does the XPages log files say about the error? If you can not get to the XPages log files on the server directly, then use XPages Log File Reader from OpenNTF to get easy access to the log files from a browser.

Comment: Thanks, Per. There is further info in the XPages log file: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: eu.linqed.debugtoolbar.DebugToolbar incompatible with eu.linqed.debugtoolbar.DebugToolbar I'm using the original version of the Debug Toolbar - not the OSGI plugin. That lead me to this thread https://lostinxpages.com/2013/08/26/java-still-vexing-me-in-xpages/  Martin Rolph's suggestion worked for me : "fix it by adding this xsp.property
xsp.application.forcefullrefresh=true"

Comment: Ahh, your comment edit beat me to it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the `ClassCastException` problem you mention in your comment, it sounds like the fix will be to turn on "Refresh entire application when design changes" in the Xsp Properties for the database.

It's off by default, but I've found that it's best to turn it on 100% of the time - when off, the runtime tries to be clever about not reloading everything, but it's imperfect about it and leads to that specific trouble frequently.

Comment: Thanks Jesse - you answered as I was commenting!!